# Is there a way to run django alongside a lampp stack?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, django

I intend to move my webserver (ubuntu) from php to django.

I have working php scripts, and have tested some django locally. Now I want to run both on my webserver, but following various tutorials for setting up django (with mod_wsgi) has led to internal server errors.

Is there something fundamental I am missing?

**Notes**

I am okay with running django out of a different port for now. I haven't pulled that off with virtual hosts yet.

I am also okay with running django out of a subfolder, but I feel that may make the django code harder to develop across local/remote machines.

Comment: 500 errors always leave something in server logs. Check them out and post here if there will still be any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind giving providing us with:

1. apache configuration you used to set this up
2. output from the error logs ? 5xx errors must leave something in
   apache error logs

without the above we may just be playing some sort of guessing game...
But to answer your question - it is possible to run php and django on the same server - should in fact be possible to run it in the same virtual host.